# font spacing becomes wider when using Latex

Tags: matlab, latex, tex

I run MatLab in Mac systems. When I use the code in plot:

```
xlabel('Example', 'Interpreter','LaTex')
```

then the font spacing becomes wider, like `'E x a m p l e'`. Does anyone know how to change the font spacing to make it more compressed?

Comment: I'm guessing R2013a+?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this on 2012b under windows, don't have a mac to try. Still, could you give a full reproducible example including a simple plot?

Comment: Unable to reproduce with R2013a